# Как задать значение переменной, равное ширине объекта в html?

Tags: javascript

Нужно задать в переменную width ширину элемента с классом imagesLi. Я уже попробывал это сделать, но безуспешно. Либо нужно сделать это как то по другому. Так же нужно учесть что использовать я могу сейчас только чистый js.
JS

```
var width = document.querySelector(".imagesLi").clientWidth;
var list = document.querySelector(".images");
var pictures = document.querySelectorAll(".imagesLi");  
var position = 0;  
document.querySelector(".prev").onclick = function() {
    position += width; // вычисляем положение картинки
    // рассчитываем положение последней картинки
    position = Math.min(position, 0)
    list.style.marginLeft = position + "px";
};
document.querySelector(".next").onclick = function() {
    position -= width; // вычисляем положение картинки
    // последнее передвижение вправо может быть не на 3, а на 2 или 1 элемент 
    position = Math.max(position, -width * (pictures.length - 1));
    list.style.marginLeft = position + "px";
};
```

html

```
<div class="carousel"> 
                <input type="button" class="arrow prev" value="<">
                <div class="gallery">
                    <ul class="images">
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/Бомбер (1).jpg"></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/Кепка (1).jpg"></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/Полотенце (2).jpg"></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/Шапка1.jpg"></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/Шорты1 (1).jpg"></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/people_7_man_hoodie_oversize_front_melange_500.jpg"></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/people_5_man_winter_jacket_front_black_500.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/people_4_manshortfull_front_white_500 (1).jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/people_4_manshortfull_front_white_500.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/people_7_man_hoodie_oversize_front_darkblue_500 (1).jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/people_7_man_hoodie_oversize_front_terracotta_500.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/Полотенце (2).jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/Шорты1 (1).jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="imagesLi"><img src="CtImg/Шорты1 (3).jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="arrow next" value=">">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи можно ипользовать

```
domRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(domRect.width, domRect.height);
```

> rect - DOMRect объект с 8-ми свойствами:
>
> left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height

либо

```
let style = window.getComputedStyle(element [, pseudoElt]);
console.log(style.width, style.height);
```

> Метод Window.getComputedStyle() возвращает объект, содержащий значения всех CSS-свойств элемента, полученных после применения всех активных таблиц
> стилей, и завершения базовых вычислений значений, которые они могут
> содержать. Некоторые CSS-свойства доступны через API, предоставляемые объектом, или индексацию по именам CSS-свойств.

Это и проще и надежнее чем пытаться вычислить эти свойства самостоятельно.

[дополнительно о getComputedStyle](http://code.mu/ru/javascript/manual/dom/getComputedStyle/)